# Re-usable Field Layouts

Tags: field, admin, layout

I've Googled & searched on here, but have not been able to find the answer I need.

I come from using Advanced Custom Fields in the WP environment, and one feature that was great about ACF was being able to define the templates a field grouping would/can show on.

Take Craft for example. I have a grouping of fields that when combined form the banner "field layout" for a section. However, that "field layout" can be used on multiple other sections and even single pages. Without me having to re-create it on every single or section, is there a way that's much more efficient?

I am also using the Reasons plugin https://github.com/mmikkel/Reasons-Craft which enables me conditional fields. And I believe this is where the efficiency concerns are coming from. Because I am having to set the conditionals on each field layout. And if I decide to change something, I will need to change it across all other field layouts.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there's no way to re-use a Field Layout in Craft.

You might want to consider adding a feature request at http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com.